# How to get the sound working in the Android Emulator

Tags: audio, android-emulator

Can anybody help me with enabling the sound in the Android Emulator? I've been trying furiously to get it to work, but to no avail... I've tried setting the start up option `-audio "winaudio"` in Eclipse, I've set the Android Virtual Device which I use to enable `Audio playback support` & `Audio recording support`, but I still don't get any sound from the Emulator.

I'm running the Emulator from Eclipse Helios (with the Android plugin), on a Windows7 32bit OS.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/3f8c496343ba2d66) (delete snapshots.img and restart emulator).  Applies to Honeycomb final (3.0).

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't apply to my situation. I use Android 2.2 as my target, and I already don't use the snapshot option.